# Is there a word for someone who loves authority?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

I'm trying to think of a word to describe a person who loves/sucks up to authority figures. I'm hoping for a phase like "boot licker" but without the police authority context.
Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this will fit your context, I would tentatively recommend **ass-kisser**: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ass-kisser

Comment: Sycophant, crawler, toady.